# meaning of the phrase "make a break" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/RE4_wYl97ds). It is at 13 minute and 30 second. The context is the teacher made a spelling mistake. When he notices it he correctes it and says:

> Sorry about that, guys. I **made a break** there.

Did he say sorry for making a pause or by the word *break* he was referring to the mistake. It seems to me that he mean a pause. If I am right then what is the word *there* there for?

Comment: I think he means that he departed from the script and ad libbed his comments regarding not putting a 's after 'achilles' when we say achilles' heel. So starting from "and also, this is possessive...' up to where he says 'Sorry...", I think that was all ad libbed and should not have happened.  'Made a break' means he broke (or diverged) from the script for a few seconds.

Comment: It's not really clear what he means, but the explanation by James is certainly plausible. Not all speakers make sense all the time :)